# jquery mobile - style icon-position not working collapsible set

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This makes no sense, true. I'm trying to use a simple collapsible set and just un-style it and change the color on links etc. First task - change the icon and move it to the right instead of left. I'm trying to use `data-iconpos="right"` in the same manner I used `data-collapsed="true"` but it doesn't seem to work. None of the prescribed jQuery data- functions like that seem to work, like the theme change, not a,b or c. What am I missing here? This should be super easy according to the docs!

Live view: https://www.ubat.com/mobile/test.html

Page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="css/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="css/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/kxv5fxv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Hello world</p>

    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 2.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- /content --> 

</div>
<!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `data-iconpos="right"` works fine for me in jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2VBb/)). Maybe upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very outdated (alpha!) version of jQuery Mobile. The latest one is [1.2.0](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html) and collapsible sets with custom icon position did not come until version [1.1.0](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html)

Please upgrade both, jQuery and jQuery Mobile versions for your code to work.

Comment: omg I didn't even notice. THANKS! {duh}

Answer (score 0):

Something I often run into with jQuery Mobile is that a lot more classes and elements get added to the DOM at run-time, so your CSS styles need to take that new structure into consideration.  I'm not suggesting a "jQuery way" of solving your problem using their data attributes, but this will help you when you run into things you want to change that don't have built-in options.

Below is just one of the two collapsable sections.  I tried to space it for readability (it's still messy).

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" class="ui-collapsible-set">
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-collapsible-contain">

  <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-up-c" data-theme="c">

      <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Section 1
          <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span>
        </span>

        <span data-theme="d" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow">
          <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all ui-corner-top">
            <span class="ui-btn-text"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus"></span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </h3>
  <div class="ui-collapsible-content" aria-hidden="false">
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

A way that you could move the button icon to the right would be to do this in CSS:

```
  .ui-collapsible-heading a span.ui-btn{
    left: inherit;
    right: 6px; /* Previously left was 6px */
  }
```

I find the best way to work through these kinds of problems is to crack open the inspector in your browser and see the final structure that jQuery Mobile has created.